# Conditions in SonarQube Quality Gates not working properly

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Number of critical issues are 4 on my project. I have configured a condition 'Critical Issues' with 2 measure in the following order.

1. 'delta since previous analysis' 'is greater than' 0

2. 'Value' 'is greater than' 6

[Please find screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSq3j.jpg)

I had forcefully introduced a critical error and run sonar. I thought it should fail because of above 1st condition but to my surprise it got passed. 
After doing multiple permutations and combinations I got to know that a unique 'Condition' should only be configured once. If a unique 'Condition' is used more than once then one which is configured later is used by Sonar and the one which is configured earlier is ignored.

According to Sonar documentation - http://www.sonarqube.org/quality-gates-shall-your-projects-pass/
'Quality Gates can be thought of in two different ways. At the practical level, they’re collections of what were once called alerts, and are now known simply as “conditions”. At the abstract level, they’re logic gates, AND-ing together all the conditions in the set to determine whether or not your project can pass.'

I could not find any information on internet to prove my findings and even sonar documentation contradicts it. Has anyone faced this issue before? Could someone confirm that a 'Condition' for example 'Critical Issues' should only be configured once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple conditions on metric(s) are definitely supported for configuring Quality Gates in SonarQube, and the documentation is in line with that.

The behaviour you are observing is most likely due to a bug present in SonarQube 5.2, 5.3, 5.4 , preventing analysis to succeed if there are multiple Quality Gate conditions on same metric, see [SONAR-7276](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7276) for more details.

Comment: I am facing this issue on Version 4.5.4 as well